# black jack variance

Tags: statistics, covariance

Is it correct to compute variance in Blackjack using Bernoulli distribution?
For example:

$p = 41\%$ is the probability of winning

$q = 9\%$ is the probability of tieing

$t = 50\%$ is the probability of losing

so the variance for $118$ hands is $p\cdot(q+t)\cdot118$.

So what is the probability of winning only $30$ hands out of $118$?

Comment: What do you mean by "only 30 hands of 118" ? It is exact 30 hands or at most 30 hands ?

Comment: I mean exactly 30/118

Comment: with a variance of 28,5442  and a mean of 48,38 it is equal to

Comment: ca 3,5 SD so it has a probability of 1/400 ca.

Comment: is it a good approximation?

Comment: What values have you input into the formula of the binomial distribution ? Or have you made an approximation ? If yes, how ?

Comment: var = p⋅(q+t)⋅118 = 28,5442

Comment: SD = Sqrt(28,5442).

Comment: mean = p * 118 = 48,38

Comment: so (48,38 - 30)/Sqrt(28,5442) = ca 3,5 SD

Comment: or more exactly 3,4402227953486092930224595723267

Comment: according to this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule

Comment: is this correct? the game is rtg game

Comment: $${118\choose30}p^{30}(1-p)^{118-30}$$